# How to add this People Picker in Sharepoint form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-foundation, development

How can I achieve a picker like this:
[image]

with this `check control` and that `book icon` I don't know how to call it. For data source for this picker should be a sharepoint list.

All I could make till now was this picker:

[image]

But I need the first one. Could any one help me on how to achieve the first data picker?

Thanks

Comment: Is it Client side people picker or server side people picker?

Comment: it is client side, but i you now how to make it in server side it not problem

Comment: So do you need it for server side or client side?

Comment: @M.Qassas I need it for serverside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `PeoplePicker` control in Visual WebPart in SSOM , Try to add the `PeoplePicker` control at your **front code** as the following:

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="spPeoplePicker"  runat="server" Width="100" SelectionSet="User" />
```

---

In your **code behind** try to get the value of the `PeoplePicker` control as the following

```
SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID);

SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb();

SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists["PeoplePicker"];

oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

int iPeople = spPeoplePicker.ResolvedEntities.Count;

SPListItem itemToAdd = list.Items.Add();

for (int i = 0; i < iPeople; i++)

{

PickerEntity peEntity = spPeoplePicker.ResolvedEntities[i] as PickerEntity;

SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(peEntity.Key);

itemToAdd["UserName"] = user;

itemToAdd.Update();
}
```

For more details check [How to call a people picker in visual web part in sharepoint2013](http://sharepointbyte.com/how-to-call-a-people-picker-in-visual-web-part-in-sharepoint-4/)

Comment: is it working good but I want to select items from a list called `employees` not from active directory. do you understand what I mean ?

Comment: I think in this case, you would do it manually , it need more development :(

Answer (score 5):

Client side people picker in SharePoint:

Below are the JS files required to load for client side people picker using JSOM.

```
clienttemplates.js
clientforms.js
clientpeoplepicker.js
autofill.js
sp.js
sp.runtime.js
sp.core.js
```

Please put below html in HTML file

```
<div id="peoplePickerDiv"></div>
```

Please put below code in JS file.

```
// Run your custom code when the DOM is ready.   
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // Specify the unique ID of the DOM element where the  
    // picker will render.  
    initializePeoplePicker('peoplePickerDiv');  
});  
// Render and initialize the client-side People Picker.  
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {  
    // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.  
    var schema = {};  
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';  
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;  
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;  
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;  
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;  
    schema['Width'] = '280px';  
    // Render and initialize the picker.  
    // Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial   
    // PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines  
    // picker properties.  
    this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);  
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I have the same code with you homie and I have the same picker but I want to create an dialog picker, just like in first picture I posted

Answer (score 3):

You can customize the form with InfoPath. In InfoPath form, you will get the same control.

Comment: I cannot use infopath

Comment: I think this will help you.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144266/people-picker-icon-is-not-showing-inside-the-built-in-new-edit-forms-while-it